The smallest gap between integers when they are shrink to the interval $[0,2]$ at an exponential rate of powers of $2$
For example, $23$ and $44$. The half of $23$ is $11.5$, and the half is $5.75$, and ... finally, we will get $23/16$. And for $44$, we will get $44/32$. So, the gap will be 1/16. Then my question is, is there a lower bound that is above 0 for any integer pairs？
Background: I came up with this question when reading about the Interval Theory in Music. I have a vague question: since the tones within an octave are the harmonics scaled down into intervals $[0,2]$, can we fill the entire octave with enough harmonics?

You can divide any positive integer by a power of $2$ to get the result in the range $[1,2)$.  There is no lower limit to the gap between the results of two integers.  An easy way to see it is to consider the integers $2^n, 2^n+1$ for large $n$.  You divide both by $2^n$ to get in range and you get $1, 1+\frac 1{2^n}$ so the gap can be made as small as you want.
